# Aligning matrices by their top row

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices, arrays

I'm writing a little array whose elements are matrices of different sizes, and I want them aligned by their top rows.

Here's the sort of thing:

```
\documenstyle{article}
\use{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{array}{ccc}
I_2&I_3&I_4\\
\hline
\begin{bmatrix}
   1&0\\ 0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\end{document}
```

But the matrices are vertically centred:

[image: LaTeX matrices]

I can get the matrices vertically aligned by their top rows by using `raisebox` but this is fiddly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    I_2&I_3&I_4\\
    \hline
    \rule{0mm}{11mm}\raisebox{4mm}{\begin{bmatrix}
      1&0\\ 0&1
    \end{bmatrix}}
    &
    \raisebox{2mm}{\begin{bmatrix}
      1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1
    \end{bmatrix}}
    &
    \begin{bmatrix}
      1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX matrices aligned]

This is the effect I want - but surely there's a better way of obtaining this alignment than trial-and-error with `raisebox`?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `\belowbaseline` macro of the `stackengine` package.  It will place the top of its argument a given distance below the baseline.  The distance is given either as an optional argument (`\belowbaseline[<gap>]{...}`), or else may be set as the default optional argument via `\setstackgap{S}{<gap>}`.

There is a comparable `\abovebaseline` macro for setting the bottom of an object at a given vertical level relative to the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
I_2&I_3&I_4\\
\hline
\belowbaseline[-3pt]{$\begin{bmatrix}
   1&0\\ 0&1
\end{bmatrix}$}
&
\belowbaseline[-3pt]{$\begin{bmatrix}
   1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$}
&
\belowbaseline[-3pt]{$\begin{bmatrix}
   1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `$` delimiters in the `\belowbaseline` argument can be eliminated if `\stackMath` (rather than the default `\stackText`) is in force.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `delarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{delarray,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
I_2&I_3&I_4\\
\midrule
\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{@{}cc@{}}\rbrack
   1&0\\ 0&1
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{@{}ccc@{}}\rbrack
   1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{@{}cccc@{}}\rbrack
   1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1
\end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The spacing of the horizontal rule is better with `\midrule` from `booktabs`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the environment `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` which has a key `t`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{ccc}
I_2&I_3&I_4\\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{10pt}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[t]
   1&0\\ 0&1
\end{bNiceMatrix}
& 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[t]
   1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1
\end{bNiceMatrix}
& 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[t]
   1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]