# Vertical centering of matrices inside table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, matrices

I'm trying to center my table contents both vertically and horizontally. The table contains both `Bmatrix` and `bmatrix` elements. Only the first column is completely centered. The second column is only horizontally centered even though I set both columns using `m{...}`:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Set Representation} & \textbf{Binary Representation} \\ \hline
$U =  \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{Bmatrix}$          & $U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 15$                \\[.5cm] \hline
$S_1 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{Bmatrix}$                & $S_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 3$              \\[.5cm] \hline
$S_2 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 \end{Bmatrix}$                  &  $S_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 1$              \\[.5cm] \hline
$S_3 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{Bmatrix}$             & $S_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 5$              \\[.5cm] \hline
$S_4 = \begin{Bmatrix} 4 \end{Bmatrix}$                  & $S_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 8$              \\[.5cm] \hline
\end{tabular}%\quad}
\caption{\textbf{Conversion from set to binary representation}}\label{table:setToBin}
\end{table}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: The right column is not centering vertically.]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help of the `makecell` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\[\setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells % <--- for vertical space around cells contents
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Set Representation} & \textbf{Binary Representation}      \\
    \hline
U =  \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{Bmatrix}
    &   U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 15    \\
    \hline
S_1 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{Bmatrix}
    &   S_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 3   \\
    \hline
S_2 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 \end{Bmatrix}
    &   S_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 1    \\
    \hline
S_3 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{Bmatrix}
    &   S_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 5   \\
    \hline
S_4 = \begin{Bmatrix} 4 \end{Bmatrix}
    &   S_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 8   \\
    \hline
\end{array}%
\]
    \caption{Conversion from set to binary representation}
\label{table:setToBin}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385712/120578) of @StevenB.Segletes you can use `\belowbaseline` command of `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}       

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Set Representation} & \textbf{Binary Representation}\\ \hline
$U =  \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{Bmatrix}$        & \belowbaseline[-3pt]{$U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 15$ }              \\[.5cm] \hline
$S_1 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{Bmatrix}$           & \belowbaseline[-3pt]{$S_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 3$ }             \\[.5cm] \hline
$S_2 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 \end{Bmatrix}$                  &  \belowbaseline[-3pt]{$S_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 1$   }           \\[.5cm] \hline
$S_3 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{Bmatrix}$             &\belowbaseline[-3pt]{ $S_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 5$  }           \\[.5cm] \hline
$S_4 = \begin{Bmatrix} 4 \end{Bmatrix}$                  & \belowbaseline[-3pt]{$S_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 8$    }          \\[.5cm] \hline
\end{tabular}%\quad}
\caption{\textbf{Conversion from set to binary representation}}\label{table:setToBin}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can only reproduce the matrices with oversized delimiters if I use

```
\linespread{1.667}
```

With

```
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
```

the delimiters have the correct size.

You can insert a strut in the first column; moreover I suggest to use `w{c}{5cm}`, if you want fixed size, instead of the `m` specifier, but I don't think it's sound, so I propose a different realization with `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second table
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\captionsetup{font=bf}

\newcommand{\bs}{\vphantom{$\Big|$}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| >{\bs}w{c}{5cm} | w{c}{5cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Set Representation} & \textbf{Binary Representation} \\
\hline
$U   = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $U   = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 15$ \\
\hline
$S_1 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $S_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 3$ \\
\hline
$S_2 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $S_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 1$ \\
\hline
$S_3 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $S_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 5$ \\
\hline
$S_4 = \begin{Bmatrix} 4 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $S_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 8$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Conversion from set to binary representation}\label{table:setToBin}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ cc }
\toprule
\textbf{Set Representation} & \textbf{Binary Representation} \\
\midrule
$U   = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $U   = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 15$ \\
\addlinespace
$S_1 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $S_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 3$ \\
\addlinespace
$S_2 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $S_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 1$ \\
\addlinespace
$S_3 = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $S_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 5$ \\
\addlinespace
$S_4 = \begin{Bmatrix} 4 \end{Bmatrix}$ &
  $S_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 8$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Conversion from set to binary representation}\label{table:setToBin2}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Final note: there should be no `\textbf` in the body of `\caption`; such formatting decision are best done on a global basis with the `caption` package.

[image]